# Spark gap Electroboom

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism, coil, spark, flux

I was watching this electroboom video on emp devices and he showed this simple circuit.
My question was why is the spark gap in parallel with the coil? I know that the spark gap will act as a HV switch, so when the voltage will be high it will act as a short. But I cannot see what that will do. It will just short the HV generator? A solution I understand is if you would swap the capacitor with the spark gap, so the capacitor will charge and when enough charge has accumelated it will surpass the gap and so on.

(11:11, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5M6YKR7wUw)

[image: Electroboom with simple emp system,]

Comment: It's about making an oscillator that's tuned to a specific frequency, hence the equation below.

Comment: The voltage drop across capacitor is opposite in polarity to the voltage drop across inductor.  At resonance they are the largest.

Comment: @SimonB I do understand now that it is used as an oscillating circuit, but I don't see what the function of the spark gap is in that circuit.

Comment: See if this helps you understand:  https://www.richieburnett.co.uk/operation.html